# How to populate JSON dump from a form to a django template?

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary

I am importing `POST` request from a form `template.html` to my `view.py` by using

```
data=json.dumps(request.POST)
```

The data at `view.py` is in this format:

```
{"5": "25", "4": "28", "6": "21"}
```

While running any dictionary syntax on it, the error pops as this data is in a string form. How do convert this to a dictionary?
Further, I need to populate the 'key' and 'value' of this dictionary to a template.

Please help me out?

Comment: `request.POST` is a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> a = '{"5": "25", "4": "28", "6": "21"}'
>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>
>>> 
>>> import ast
>>> x = ast.literal_eval(a)
>>> type(x)
<type 'dict'>
>>> 
>>> x.keys()
['5', '4', '6']
>>> x.values()
['25', '28', '21']
```

> > > 

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to do `json.dumps(request.POST)`, `request.POST` will be a dictionary.

If you are posting json values in request body, you will have to do `json.loads(request.body)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a json object, it's not yet a dictionary.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html (2.7)

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/json.html (3.4)

the documentation shows you how to handle json. you can just parse it and access keys to get the values as you are used to!

```
data_dict = json.loads(data)
print(data_dict['5'])
> "25"
```